# Getting "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" after prompting user for input

Tags: c

Switch statement results in "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" regardless of the case.

I tried changing the data type of "command" but can't get any other result.

```
    char command;
    int temp;

    while(1) {
            printf("Enter command ('d'/'m'/'s'/'r'): ");
            scanf("%c", command);
            printf("\n");

            switch(command) {
                    case 'd' :
                            printf("display which employee (0-19)?\n");
                            scanf("%i", temp);
                            //display(temp);
                            printf("displayed");
                            break;
                    case 'm' :
                            printf("modify which employee (0-19)?\n");
                            scanf("%i", temp);
                            //modify(temp);
                            printf("modified");
                            break;
                    case 's' :
                            //save();
                            printf("saved");
                            break;
                    case 'r' :
                            //retrieve();
                            printf("retrieved");
                            break;
                    default :
                            printf("Command not recognized\n");
            }
    }
```

Expected to print the action according to the relevant case. Instead it just prints the "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" message regardless.

Comment: `scanf("%i", temp);` --> `scanf("%i", &temp);` Since `temp` is an `int` variable, you need to provide `&` to store user input into it. Also read compiler warning carefully & solve them, don't ignore them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%c` format specifier expects the address of a `char`, i.e. a `char *` to be passed in.  You're passing in a `char` instead.  The same goes for `%i` and `int` further down.  Using the wrong format specifier invokes [undefined behaivor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which is in this case manifests as a crash.

You need to pass the *address* of the variables in question so that `scanf` can modify them.  Also, for `%c` you should have a space in the format string before it to consume any whitespace left in the input buffer.

So you want:

```
scanf(" %c", &command);
```

And:

```
scanf("%i", &temp);
```